# Should I use a screw or anchor bolt to hold a metal box to the wall?

Tags: walls, screws, security

Which type of bolt is best for securing a metal box to a wall to prevent it being pulled away: Screw Bolt or Anchor Bolt?

And by Screw Bolt I mean this:

[image: Screw bolt]

And by Anchor Bolt I mean this:

[image: Anchor bolt]
<sub>(source: [northerntool.com](https://www.northerntool.com/images/product/2000x2000/343/34352_2000x2000.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Depends on what the wall is made of, where you're anchoring to it, what forces the box is going to put on the fastener... We can't give a good answer unless you give us more details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: So it's going into a brick wall. The box itself, one half is open and the other has a drawer. So I just don't want it to be pulled off.

Comment: How much weight, how much torque when the drawer is extended...? My instinctive response is that the anchor bolt, in an appropriately sized hole, will hold better but a malliable anchor insert used with the screw bolt (or an ordinary sheet-metal screw) might hold as well or better. I used anchors to support the lumber rack, but that was decided "by guess and by golly".

Comment: If you use the screw bolt with a hammer drill to pre-tap, I'd recommend pushing a small amount of PL into the hole first to both help fill gaps and provide better holding power.

Comment: Those anchor bolts are for concrete or stone and require a precisely-sized hole, in which case they are very strong. Red clay bricks are too soft and the anchors will pull out. What kind of brick?

Answer (score 1):

I'm old school: I still use lags and shields. They "never" pull out when installed properly.

[image]

([alliedboltinc.com](http://www.alliedboltinc.com/product/1/2-inch-SHORT-LAG-SHIELD~1413.aspx))

Comment: Why do you have quotation marks around the "never"?

Comment: "What, never?" "Well, hardly ever..."

Comment: I'd tend to agree; I've never put 'em in, but they sure as hell don't like coming out. The fastener shaft usually snaps first before it will dislodge the wedges.